# Dominoes initial draw probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I draw $7$ dominoes from a pool of $28$ dominoes, what is the probability that my seven dominoes include both the 5-5 and the 6-4?  Are my calculations correct?

Possible 7-card draws $= \dfrac{28!}{21!7!} = 1,184,040$

Draws including 5-5 & 6-4 $= \dfrac{2!}{1!} \cdot \dfrac{26!}{21!5!} = 2 \cdot 65,780 = 131,560$

Probability = $\dfrac{131,560}{1,184,040} = 11.1111\%$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You should explain your reasoning since that makes it easier for readers to detect any errors you may have made.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  $\frac {2{26\choose 5}}{{28\choose 7}}$, thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your denominator is correct.  There are $$\binom{28}{7}$$ ways to select $7$ of the $28$ dominoes in the set.

For the favorable cases, you must select the two dominoes in question and five of the other $28 - 2 = 26$ dominoes.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{26}{5} = \binom{26}{5}$$

Therefore, the probability of selecting both 5-5 and 6-4 initially is
$$\frac{\dbinom{26}{5}}{\dbinom{28}{7}}$$

It is not clear to me why you have an extra factor of $2$ in there.  Each pair of numbers appears exactly once in a set of dominoes, which is why there are $$\binom{7}{2} + \binom{7}{1} = 28$$ dominoes in a set.  The first term represents the number of ways of selecting two different numbers from the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, while the second term represents the number of ways of picking two identical numbers from the same set.  In particular, there is one domino with two fives and one domino which displays a four and a six.

Comment: Thank you! So the correct probability is 65,780/1,184,040, which equals .05555555?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.